# Best Approach for combining static text with data into a ListView

Tags: java, android

I have some values coming from a datasource that I have control over. I am stuffing those values into a ListView. The values go something like this:

"You have X books overdue". This is a silly example but it gets the point I'm trying to understand. Everything EXCEPT X is static however when the ArrayAdapter populates the ListView the only thing that shows is X. This of course make sense.

I can think of two ways to solve this problem. One is to modify my data source so the entire message is provided; this makes life simple on the GUI side but my database colleagues are definitely going to frown.

On the other hand I can find the TextView by id and concatenate EXCEPT ListView is just a representation of the underlying data so really I would modify the data AFTER getting it from the db then update / redraw the list view?

Comment: That calls for a custom listadapter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attach a Binder to your list adapter and modify the data that gets set into it. Assuming you have an adapter called `myAdapter`:

```
myAdapter.setViewBinder(new MyViewBinder());

public class MyViewBinder implements ViewBinder {
    @Override
    public boolean setViewValue(View view, Object data, String text){
        if(view instanceof TextView){
            ((TextView)view).setText(String.format("You have %s books overdue",text));
        }
    }
}
```

When you reach the `ViewBinder` in your code, the program is trying to populate your list. You'd then check if the view is as instance of `TextView` and if so, using the variable `text` which in this case is the element from position X of your data source, we create a String with format including the source data.

If you have multiple views being populated for each row, you can check the id with `view.getId()`

Without a ViewBinder, your data gets mapped to the views as specified on the adapter, but with the ViewBinder in place you can do all sorts of cool stuff like, alternative background color for the rows or making a view clickable depending on the content of the source, the possibilities are endless.

Comment: Very cool learned something new. How would you expand it to this scenario. You have X books overdue. You have answered. The next text view says "You have X days to return them before we send Guido out". I would image perhaps a case statement or if then else if view.name == ""

Comment: You can check the view id as usual with `view.getId()` and match it. Or even check the data like you say.

Comment: This is interesting. It is concatenating the numeric value from my strings.xml?    R.string.str_PrevRepsStatic + " %s", text

Comment: That's not how it works. To get a string, you need to do: `getString(R.string.idhere)` otherways it will give the id(integer) for that resource. `getString()` returns a String, while just using the id, returns what it is, an integer.

Comment: If I could give you another point I would. Thanks for the patience with this noob.

Comment: @user1278561 People being patient like I am now, made me the programmer I wanted to be. I couldn't tell apples from oranges when I first came here and reading and asking took me far, you are welcome.